# Using composer dialogs in a C# bot

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, visual-composer

I created a C# bot with bot framework 4.14.1. Some dialogs are written in C# and others are created with the Bot Framework Composer. Now I want to run the composer dialogs inside the C# bot. In later versions of the Bot Framework I can do the following:

```cs
var composerDialogResource = resourceExplorer.GetResource("Composer_Dialog.dialog");
var composerDialog = resourceExplorer.LoadType<AdaptiveDialog>(composerDialogResource );
```

That worked fine. But with the new version of Bot Framework I get the following exception:

> "composer.dialog error: Could not create an instance of type
> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Dialog. Type is an interface or abstract
> class and cannot be instantiated."

Does anyone has solved this problem?
Regards
Andreas

Comment: I need to do the same, does this work for you?